# FFmpeg Error "No such filter: 'libvmaf' Mac

Tags: macos, command-line, ffmpeg

I want to use FFmpeg to calculate PSNR for video sequences.
At first I installed **libvmaf** with the instruction from [here](http://quarantine.tu-berlin.de:32224/?dmVyPTEuMDAxJiYwZjdkOGRlNTRiMzIyZjZlYT01RUNCN0Q5RV81MDk4MV80NTQwXzEmJjhjNzNlNzQ1YTQ5ZDIyMz0xMjIyJiZ1cmw9aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZnaXRodWIlMkVjb20lMkZOZXRmbGl4JTJGdm1hZiUyRnRyZWUlMkZtYXN0ZXIlMkZsaWJ2bWFm) and [here](https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/issues/406). I installed ffmpeg like [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS). I tried for a test:

```
ffmpeg -i output4.mpg -i output1.mpg -lavfi libvmaf -f null -
```

But I get an Error (below). I think I could solve it with `./configure --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3` or `./configure --enable-libvmaf` but unfortunately I can not run it (I don't know how).

I hope anyone can help me to solve this problem.

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags=-fno-stack-check --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'output4.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:09.88, start: 0.533367, bitrate: 363 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 352x288 [SAR 178:163 DAR 1958:1467], 104857 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
Input #1, mpeg, from 'output1.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:10.01, start: 0.533367, bitrate: 345 kb/s
    Stream #1:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 352x288 [SAR 178:163 DAR 1958:1467], 104857 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7ffedbe23180] No such filter: 'libvmaf'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [libvmaf filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#libvmaf):

> It requires Netflix’s vmaf library (libvmaf) as a pre-requisite. After
> installing the library it can be enabled when compiling `ffmpeg` with:
> `--enable-libvmaf --enable-version3`.

Your `ffmpeg` is missing the required `--enable-libvmaf --enable-version3` configuration options.

Easy solution is to download an already compiled `ffmpeg` from [evermeet.cx](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) or use the Homebrew tap [homebrew-ffmpeg](https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg):

```
brew tap homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg
brew install homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg --with-libvmaf
```